# Multiple rails3 applications conditional deployments

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.2, capistrano, rvm-capistrano

With an application that needs scaling, multiple instances of an application need to be deployed at different times.

```
staging.theapp.tld (for admin testing)
sandbox.theapp.tld (for user testing, actually in development mode for better logging)
theapp.tld (actual production mode. To be run with and without 'www.' prefix)
```

Deployment needs to occur in one of three ways:
- staging alone (to test stuff in production mode)
- staging + sandbox
- sandbox + actual production mode

Production mode will have multiple instances: a master server and any number of VPS slaves - say two.  Thus,

```
master.theapp.tld
vps1.theapp.tld
vps1.theapp.tld
```

Underneath, postgresql is running the master-slave process for updating data to VPSes.

Given the number of variables involved, and the lack of setting-up multiple server experience, the number of possibilities of gumming up the works becomes exponential... the app's relevant components are:

```
gem 'capistrano', '2.14.2'
gem 'rvm-capistrano', '1.2.7'
gem 'pg', '0.17.1'
```

How should capistrano be thus configured?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question. Instead of providing specific answers I can only suggest a couple things:

- switch to `capistrano3`. It's been a while since it was released.
- consider using some of the [capistrano-plugins](https://github.com/capistrano-plugins) instead of starting from scratch
- [capistrano-unicorn-nginx](https://github.com/capistrano-plugins/capistrano-unicorn-nginx) pretty much supports everything you mentioned in the post with minimal config: multiple apps on a single server as well as multi-server support.
- [capistrano-postgres](https://github.com/capistrano-plugins/capistrano-postgresql) also supports single and multi-server configurations. It does not yet have support for postgresql master-slave setup so that part would have to be done on its own.